# How to trim HH:MM:SS from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form input field with a value format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
How do I trim / remove HH:MM:SS from the above format using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: `dateString.slice(0, 10)`

Comment: If my answer is working for you then please mark as acceptable, so its better for others also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input#someID").val($("#someID").val().substring(0 , 10));
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" value="2017-01-19 12:10:07" id = "someID">
```

Answer (score 1):

Using split method should do the trick with more than enough extra goodies:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var date = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS";
var res = date.split(" ");
```

res now is an array with "YYYY-MM-DD" and "HH:MM:SS"

Answer (score 1):

```js
var d = '12/12/1955 12:00:00 AM';
d = d.split(' ')[0];
console.log(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no need for jQuery to use split

Answer (score -1):

```
function getDateFromString(datestring) {
var d = new Date(datestring);
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
curr_month++;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
return curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year;
}
```

Comment: This fails to pad the month and day to two digits. Also, add some explanation to your code.